# MSHTML.HTMLElementCollection type mismatch error

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am creating a script code to copy data to Excel. My code works fine until find the element I get error `type mismatch`.

```
Function Login(ID As String, Pass As String) As Boolean
 Dim objIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
 Dim ieDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
 
 Dim UserID As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
 Dim passwordID As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
 Dim loginb As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
 Dim AllHyperlinks As MSHTML.HTMLElementCollection
 Dim hyper_link As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
 Dim link As Object
    
 Set objIE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
 objIE.navigate URLstr
 
 Do Until objIE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
 Loop
 
 Set ieDoc = objIE.document
 objIE.Visible = True
 
 Application.Wait Now() + #12:00:02 AM#
 Set UserID = ieDoc.all.Item("login/")
 UserID.Value = ID
 Application.Wait Now() + #12:00:02 AM#
 Set passwordID = ieDoc.all.Item("password")
 passwordID.Value = Pass
 Application.Wait Now() + #12:00:01 AM#
 Set loginb = ieDoc.getElementsByClassName("button")(0)
 loginb.Click
 Do Until objIE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
 Loop
 Application.Wait Now() + #12:00:02 AM#
  
 Set AllHyperlinks = ieDoc.getElementsByTagName("A") 'here i Got Error
 For Each hyper_link In AllHyperlinks
     If hyper_link.innerText = "search" Then
         hyper_link.Click
         Exit For
     End If
 Next
 
 Set objIE = Nothing
End Function
```

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:showSearch(true)" title="Search" class="button" id="button_search">
<img src="images/icon_search.gif" alt="">Search
```

Comment: Could u add more detail to your question?

Comment: this markup HTML code for Button in page after login

Comment: is you element inside a parent iframe/frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the code block:

```
 Set AllHyperlinks = ieDoc.getElementsByTagName("A") 'here i Got Error
 For Each hyper_link In AllHyperlinks
     If hyper_link.innerText = "search" Then
         hyper_link.Click
         Exit For
     End If
 Next
```

Against:

```
ieDoc.getElementByID("button_search").Click
```

Comment: now i got error object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: Than the page is not fully loaded or the html is from another page.

Comment: this page reload after login

Comment: can i send console to this page ??

Comment: `Do Until objIE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE` don't work twice. You must wait in another way  the second time to load the page completly. Via a manual break with `Application.Wait...` or a loop that waits for a specific html element on the page to load. Most of the `Application.Wait ...` in your code are probably not needed.

Comment: Can you post the url?

Comment: Thanks for your reply URL is Local the page doesn't take 1 sec

Comment: Ok, one more idea. You save the reference to the document in the variable `ieDoc`. Try to renew this reference after loading the page after login with the same line of code `Set ieDoc = objIE.document` and than try `ieDoc.getElementByID("button_search").Click`.